# Spontaneous increase of vacuum energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, universe, vacuum

If the vacuum energy of the universe is not at its minimum, that is, the universe is at a false/metastable vacuum state, then it could decay into the true vacuum state.

However, if our universe is already at the true vacuum state, then, this decay would not take place.

However, in the far future, if we would wait enough time, could the true vacuum transition into a false vacuum level somehow? Or is this utterly impossible?

Answer (score 1):

**Short simplified answer**: it is impossible to *tunnel* to a higher energy state. One can only transition to an excited state via some energy input.

**Extended answer**: Without going into the details of field theory and false vacuum decay, for which I recommend the seminal paper by Coleman:

https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.1248,

I would suggest, considering simply a 1D quantum mechanical system with a potential with two minima. It could be even a square double well with two wells of different depths.

If this represents a closed system where no energy is coming in or out (as we believe our Universe is) then the question you are asking is simply what is the transition probability of the ground-state to an excited state.

In the absence of any other effect/interaction, we know that eigenstates are orthogonal so the overlap between any two different energy eigenstates is essentially zero. If you were to solve the Schrödinger equation to find the eigenstates, you will find that the bigger the difference in the heights of the wells, the more the ground-state is concentrated in the lower well and there is negligible overlap with the higher well. On the other hand, when the height of the wells are comparable, there might be a negligible overlap (depending on the width of the barrier), however always exponentially suppressed. (See Fig. 5 of https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2015/cp/c5cp00472a remember wavefunctions go to zero at infinite, they are just plotted at different hights for illustration)

The above is a simplified model but helps to highlight some features. There is no energy coming in and there is no additional interaction between states. It is required to consider interactions and meta-stable states (not only eigen-states) but this is enough to give you an idea of how suppressed such a process is.

Comment: so then this would be utterly and plainly impossible or tecnically possible but extremely unlikely? @ohneVal